# using multiple find_in_set in a single query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

one is users with "userid" column, the other one is opinion with "yes" and "no" columns.
The "yes" and "no" columns both contain comma separated values.

What I wanted is to count the number of times a "userid" appears in the "yes" column as well as the number of times it appears in the "no" column.

What I have right now is this

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(yes), COUNT(no)
FROM users LEFT JOIN opinion ON (FIND_IN_SET( userid, yes) > 0)
GROUP BY userid
```

The above works as it counts the # of times each user appears in the "yes" column but incorrectly on the "no" column. echoing "no" results to the same result as echoing "yes"

Sample data on "users"

```
1
2
3
```

Sample data on "yes"

```
1,2
1,3
2,3
1
```

Sample data on "no"

```
1,2
1,2
1,3
```

desired result is with data above:

```
users     yes    no
1         3      3
2         2      2
3         2      1
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: i'm confused. how do you on if it is a `yes` or a `no`?

Comment: what is also your desired result?

Comment: @491243 edited the question adding the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs only a little tweak. Add also a condition that joins `userID` with column `NO` on the other table. During counting of values, you also need to use `FIND_IN_SET()` inside the aggregate function `MAX()`.

```
SELECT  a.userID,
        SUM(FIND_IN_SET(a.userID, b.yes) > 0) TotalYes,
        SUM(FIND_IN_SET(a.userID, b.no) > 0) TotalNo
FROM    users a
        LEFT JOIN opinion b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.userID, b.yes) > 0 OR
                FIND_IN_SET(a.userID, b.no) > 0 
GROUP   BY a.userID
ORDER   BY a.userID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0e43/2)

Comment: thank you. that works! now what if i have another column in the opinion table called points and I want to find the sum for each user. Only users in the yes column gets points

Comment: it's a column for the opinion tables as well. every row has a corresponding point. Let's say, each of them is 2 points although they may vary. And only the users in the yes column gets to earn the point/s